# Given any $a,b$, find $A,B$ such that $a\sin(x) + b\cos(x) = A\sin(x+B)$

Tags: trigonometry

I understand that if $f''+f = 0, f(0) = a$, $f'(0) = b$ we can have $f = b\sin +a\cos$. so if $f(x) = A\sin(x+B)$, we choose $a = A\cos(B)$ and $b = A\sin(B)$

How do we find $a$ and $b$ conversely?

Comment: Hint: $$\sin(x+B)=\sin x \cos B+\sin B\cos x$$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\theta$ be such that $\cos \theta = a/\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ and $\sin \theta = b/\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$. Then $$a\sin(x) + b\cos(x) = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}(\cos(\theta)\sin(x) + \sin(\theta)\cos(x)) = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}\sin(x + \theta).$$

Comment: Also, $\theta = \tan^{-1} (b/a)$.

Answer (score 0):

Given any two real no $ a,b$ .we have P$(a,b)$,a point on the XY- plane .now ifO be the origin and  A = length of OP $=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. Then draw a perpendicular PM from P to x-axis. Now let OP makes an angle B with positive x-axis. Then we have[image]

$$ a=A\cos B $$ and $$ b = A\sin B $$ and hence we have-
$$ a\sin x + b\ cos x =A sin( x+B) $$

Answer (score 0):

Using dot product,

$$a\sin x+b \cos x=\langle b,a \rangle \cdot \langle \cos x ,\sin x \rangle$$

$$=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos(x-\text{atan}(a,b))$$

$$=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin(x-\text{atan}(a,b)+\frac{\pi}{2})$$

Where I define $\text{atan}(y,x)$ as giving the counterclockwise angle from the positive $x$ axis of a point $(x,y)$ to the origin. The usual counterclockwise notion of angle measure.

[image]