# Why does $R=\sqrt{5^{2}+12^{2}}=\ 13$ given that $5\sin x+12\cos x=R\sin\left(x+α\right)$?

Tags: trigonometry, angle

In an auxiliary angle question, the step subsequent to establishing that $$5\sin x+12\cos x=R\sin\left(x+α\right)$$ is $$R=\sqrt{5^{2}+12^{2}}=\ 13$$ How does one prove that the value of $R^2$ equates to $5^{2}+12^{2}$ ? I understand this has something to do with the Pythagorean Therorem, yet I am not exactly sure in what way.

All guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried expanding the RHS using that $\sin(x+\alpha)=\cos(\alpha)\sin x + \sin(\alpha)\cos x$ and then comparing the $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ coefficients with the LHS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given any $a,b$, find $A,B$ such that $a\sin(x) + b\cos(x) = A\sin(x+B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134357/given-any-a-b-find-a-b-such-that-a-sinx-b-cosx-a-sinxb) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a%5Csin%20x%2Bb%5Ccos%20x%3Dc%5Csin(x%2B%5Calpha)%24&p=2). Other duplicate questions are [How does teacher get first step?](/q/17716), [Determine the amplitude, period, and phase shift of $f(t) = 2 sin t + \sqrt{3}cos t$](/q/2727399), [Prove: $a \sin x + b \cos x = c \sin(x + d)$](/q/3447268), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we expand the right-hand side, we get:

$\begin{eqnarray} R \sin (x + \alpha) & = & R(\sin x \cos \alpha + \cos x \sin \alpha ) \\
& = & R \cos \alpha \sin x + R \sin \alpha \cos x\end{eqnarray}$

then equating that with the left-hand side gives the equations

$R \cos \alpha = 5, R \sin \alpha = 12$

and we can eliminate the $\alpha$ terms using the Pythagorean identity:

$\begin{eqnarray} (R \cos \alpha)^2 + (R \sin \alpha)^2 & = & 5^2 + 12^2 \\
R^2(\cos^2 \alpha + \sin^2 \alpha) & = & 13^2 \\
R^2 & = & 13^2 \end{eqnarray}$